Nest cannot resolve dependencies for injection of Interface type during Jest tests
I have a class, called PostService, and the constructor looks like this:
constructor(
    @InjectModel(Post.name) postModel: Model<Post>,
    @Inject(MediaStreamer) private mediaService: MediaStreamerService,
    @InjectConnection() private readonly conn: Connection
) {
    super(postModel);
    this.model = postModel;
}

where this line is causing the issue:
@Inject(MediaStreamer) private mediaService: MediaStreamerService,
by giving this error when running jest tests:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PostService (PostModel, ?, DatabaseConnection). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the
RootTestModule context.

Here's the MediaStreamer and MediaStreamerService:
export interface MediaStreamerService {
    streamMedia(folder: string, objectKey: string): Promise<StreamableFile>;

    uploadMedia(mediaFile: Array<Express.Multer.File>, userId: string): Promise<string[]>;

    moveMedia(currentPath: string, destinationPath: string, filenames: string[]): Promise<void>;
}

export const MediaStreamer = Symbol("MediaStreamer");

MediaStreamerService gets implemented by 2 classes. In the development/test environment, I only use the S3StorageMediaStreamerService:
export class S3StorageMediaStreamerService implements MediaStreamerService {

and here is my post.service.spec.ts file:
// Mock the S3 media streamer service. See below.
jest.mock("src/entities/media/media-stream.service");

describe("PostService", () => {
    let postService: PostService;
    let mediaService: S3StorageMediaStreamerService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: getConnectionToken(),
                    useValue: new MongooseConnection(),
                },
                dependencyModel<Post>(Post.name, postStub()),
                {
                    provide: MediaStreamer,
                    useValue: new S3StorageMediaStreamerService(),
                },
                PostService,
            ],
        }).compile();

    ...

and here's the mock file for the S3StorageMediaStreamerService:
export const S3StorageMediaStreamerService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    streamMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(file),
    uploadMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce("OK"),
    moveMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce("OK"),
});

Question
What could be causing that issue to say that nest cannot resolve the dependencies?
I have no problem resolving dependencies for models/connections being injected using @InjectModel, or @InjectConnection. But now for this @Inject(), I seem to be having issues that I cannot resolve.
Is it because I'm using a Symbol for MediaStreamer? Is it because I'm using an interface for the MediaStreamerService, and now I need to inject a child implementation of that?
Thanks,
Michael

Let's try to use a string as a provider token, ex: @Inject('MediaStreamer123')..., and update the test too provide: 'MediaStreamer123', ...
